# Authenticate user login to form and makes only 10 forms in django

Tags: python, html, django

The problem is that, I want that the authenticated users login into the form. And They can make only 10 forms after the 10 forms message is displayed. I have tried but the message is not displayed.

`VIEWS.PY`
def create_form(request):

```
# Creator must be authenticated
if not request. user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))
```

def create_form(request):
# Assuming the user is already authenticated
logged_in_user = request.user

```
# Set the maximum allowed forms per creator (in this case, 10)
max_forms_per_creator = 10

# Get the count of forms created by the logged-in user
form_count = Form.objects.filter(creator=logged_in_user).count()

# Check if the user has reached the form creation limit
if form_count >= max_forms_per_creator:
    
   return  render(request, "error/error.html" )
```

This program works but  it does not show the error message nor show the  error HTML page

Comment: You have two separate `create_form` functions?  Can you show the template where the user creates the form, maybe the **urls.py** as well?

Comment: yes!  Here is models .py for user :  # Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)                                                           
    Urls.py :   path('form/create', views.create_form, name="create_form"),  this is the form create URl

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two functions with the same name.  How is Django supposed to know which view function to use?  My guess is that it's just picking the first one, which is why the second is never used.  Combine them, and that *may* help:

```py
def create_form(request):

    # Creator must be authenticated
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))

    # Assuming the user is already authenticated 
    logged_in_user = request.user

    # Set the maximum allowed forms per creator (in this case, 10)
    max_forms_per_creator = 10

    # Get the count of forms created by the logged-in user
    form_count = Form.objects.filter(creator=logged_in_user).count()

    # Check if the user has reached the form creation limit
    if form_count >= max_forms_per_creator:
       return  render(request, "error/error.html" )

    # You need to add here what should happen if the user is NOT authenticated
    # AND the form_count is NOT >= 10
    return render(request, .....)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But issue is still there . I have removed one function but the main problem is that its locks the forms but it do not render the html error page .   it has else part if form is less than 10 it will able to create form .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has something to do with your templating. Certain condition is not met and you will like to redirect back to an error page. Well, tell django the exact app you are working with since error is not the name of the app. e.g . try to restructure your code like this;
appname
--template
--appname
--errorfolder
---error.html
then modify this
if form_count >= max_forms_per_creator:
return  render(request, "errorfolder/error.html" )
hope it works .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).